# Which days count when daily rate is used to calculate interest?

Tags: loans, interest

Say you get a loan on `Jan 20` with monthly payments due `15th every month`. You have the money in your hand some time in the middle of `Jan 20` already, that’s the day when the contract came to existence. The interest is counted for the exact number of days in the period.

I’d like to know what days are counted into the period. Does the first day in part of which I already have the money count? Does the due date count? It only makes sense that only one of those counts, because otherwise there would be overlaps.

- `Jan 20 to Feb 14` would mean that any day on which I had the money available for at least some time counts. But it would also imply that at the very beginning of the due date day the payment should be already there on the creditor’s account.
- `Jan 21 to Feb 15` would mean that only full days count and imply that the payment for the period can arrive at any time during the due date day.

Both of those make some kind of sense and it kind of confuses me that ⑴ it is not clearly stated in any contract I’ve seen and ⑵ it is empirically OK when the payment is done at the due date day with no fines or penalties.

My question thus distills more to: when there is a due date for a payment, does is need to be accounted at the beginning of the day, or at its end?

Comment: The answer depends on the language of the loan contract. Generally, balances count at the end of the day, but it doesn't necessarily have to be so

Answer (score -1):

Odds are very high that at the time of the loan interest was prepaid thru Fed 15th, and March 15th is when the first payment, based on a full month, is due.